# Exam package: How can I stick part and solutionbox together?

Tags: exam

I'm using the [exam class](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam) and have the problem with the `parts` enviroment in combination with the `solutionorbox` enviroment. The `part` and the corresponding `solutionorbox` should be on the same page. Here is an example that demonstrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\titledquestion{Farben}
\begin{parts}
\part[4] Question 1 \blindtext
\begin{solutionorbox}[16cm]
    \blindtext
\end{solutionorbox}
\part[4] Question 2 \blindtext
\begin{solutionorbox}[10cm]
    \blindtext
\end{solutionorbox}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to modify the `\part` command by using `etoolbox` package but it does not work with:

```
\preto{\part}{\par\nobreak\vfil\penalty 9999\vfilneg\vtop\bgroup}
```

This is the `part` definition in the *exam.cls*:

```
\def\part{%
  \@bonusfalse
  \process@part
}%
```

How can I add a `\newpage` if needed that the question and the space for a solution is on the same page without adding the `\newpage`?

Comment: I thik it is easier to use '\clearpage' between both parts, and get a second page started with the question two.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not really a good solution, but it's a start.

First of all, you have to move you `\preto` patch within the `parts` environment, because `\part` is defined there. Then, because `\part` now has a `\bgroup`, you have to end your item with an `\egroup`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\titledquestion{Farben}
\begin{parts}
\preto{\part}{\par\nobreak\vfil\penalty 9999\vfilneg\vtop\bgroup}
\part[4] Question 1 \blindtext
\begin{solutionorbox}[16cm]
    \blindtext
\end{solutionorbox}
\egroup
\part[4] Question 2 \blindtext
\begin{solutionorbox}[10cm]
    \blindtext
\end{solutionorbox}
\egroup
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting a `\filbreak` before each `\part` command.  That tries to have all the page breaks be at a `\filbreak` command, but it doesn't break the page if there's room remaining for all the text up to the next `\filbreak`.